# My module doesn't see components from app.module

Tags: angular

I have my own module (`FrameworkModule`), which is called in `import` inside `app.module`

This is my module:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    CheckFieldComponent,
  ],
  exports: [
    CheckFieldComponent,
  ],
})
export class FrameworkModule { }
```

If I use any component from `app.module`, component from `FrameworkModule` it doesn't see. `App.module` of course includes my `FrameworkModule`.

For example:
In component `xyz` (which is defined in my `FrameworkModule`) I am using `zyx` component (which is defined in `app.module`) - then `xyz` doesn't see `zyx` component.

And the error:

> Can't bind to 'xyz' since it isn't a known property of 'zyx'.

Comment: Hmm. What can I say more to explain.. If in CheckFieldComponent.html i use "<another-component></another-component>" then shows up error. Another-component is in app.module

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is by design. If you want to use components from a module, you have to import this module. Your FeatureModule does not (and can not) import your AppModule and so you cannot use components defined in your AppModule.

A common workaround is to create a third module that can be imported in your AppModule and your FeatureModule.

Example:

```
 AppModule
   imports: ChildModule1

 ChildModule1
   imports: -

 => AppModule can use components from ChildModule1 (and AppModule)
 => ChildModule1 can use only components from ChildModule1

 =====

 AppModule
   imports: ChildModule1

 ChildModule1
   imports: AppModule

 => Not possible, circular dependency

 =====

 AppModule
   imports: ChildModule1, SharedModule1

 ChildModule1
   imports: SharedModule1

 SharedModule1
   imports: -

 => AppModule can use components from ChildModule1 and SharedModule1 (and AppModule)
 => ChildModule1 can use only components from SharedModule1 (and ChildModule1)
```

Comment: Can you give me some example? I have many many components, I cant remake all of them to module

Comment: Thanks for example @Christoph_Lütjen but like I said - I have many many many components, i cant rewriting them to module. What is solution for me? One module and import all components from the project?

Comment: One option would be to create one "SharedComponentsModule" and move most of your components from the app module to this new module. But I'd recommend to create smaller modules. It's not so much work (assuming you have an IDE that gives you some support fixing broken imports). Or remove your child module and move everything to your AppModule (not recommended too).

Answer (score 1):

In any angular application that is not just an hello world exemple, it would be better to avoid declaring components in the app module.

What Christoph suggested is the best way, make yourself a shared module where you can declare all your components. It might look like a lot of work to do but it is not that much and it's just how angular work. AppModule is the root and it includes everything else, you cannot import it anywhere or you will end up with circular dependencies.

I am building a massive app and the app module itself only declares the app component, no others..

Good luck!

Comment: Okay. Hmm, what is the path of all components will be still the same, but I just move declaration of them to shared module?

Comment: Yeah you do not have to actually move the components, just declare them inside the shared module.